# Jogo da Memoria Dois jogadores

Tags: java

Tenho aqui um jogo da Memoria, mas falta implementar jogar contra outro jogador.Por exemplo eu começo a jogar, se não acertar passo para voce(outro jogador), se acertar tenho direito a tentar descobrir mais um par de cartas (casas).Como devo começar a fazer, começar a atribuir quem joga primeiro ? jogador 1 ou 2.Depois disso o que devo fazer, cada jogador joga na sua janela de jogo, e ve a jogada do outro jogador. Não consigo encontrar nenhum codigo na net de jogo da velha para dois jogadores (multijogador). Por isso isto fica muito dificil para min. 
O que fiz até agora:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.List;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.net.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;

public class MemoryGame7 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    ClassLoader cl = null;          
    public int delay = 1000; 

    public void Contador()
    {
    ActionListener counter = new ActionListener() 
    {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
        tempo++;
        TempoScore.setText("Tempo: " + tempo);
            }
    };
    new Timer(delay, counter).start();
    }

    public void updateHitMiss() 
    {
        HitScore.setText("Acertou: " + Hit);
        MissScore.setText("Falhou: " + Miss);
    PontosScore.setText("Pontos: " + Pontos);
    }

    private JFrame window = new JFrame("Jogo da Memoria");
    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500; 
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;
    private JButton exitBtn, baralharBtn, solveBtn, restartBtn, maximoBtn, definicoesBtn;
    ImageIcon ButtonIcon = createImageIcon("card1.png"); //.jpg 
    private JButton[] gameBtn = new JButton[16];
    private ArrayList<Integer> gameList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    private int Hit, Miss, Pontos, Maximo;
    public int tempo = 0;   
    private int counter = 0;
    private int[] btnID = new int[2];
    private int[] btnValue = new int[2];
    private JLabel HitScore, MissScore, TempoScore, PontosScore, MaximoScore;
    private JPanel gamePnl = new JPanel();
    private JPanel buttonPnl = new JPanel();
    private JPanel scorePnl = new JPanel();
    private JTextArea textArea;
    int player;
    private DataInputStream input;
    private JTextField id;
    private boolean myTurn;
     private DataOutputStream output;
    //private Square board[][], currentSquare;

    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) 
    {
        java.net.URL imgURL = MemoryGame7.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) 
    {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } 
    else  return null;
    }

    public MemoryGame7()
    {
        createGUI();
        createJPanels();
        setArrayListText();
        window.setTitle("Jogo da Memoria");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        Contador();

        //             INFORMAÇOES
        JPanel middlePanel=new JPanel();     
        JTextArea display=new JTextArea(12,12);
        display.setEditable(true); //false
        JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(display);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        middlePanel.add(scroll);
        window.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        display.setText("Jogador(Player) 1");

        //             CHAT 
        middlePanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(),"Informações                            Chat"));        
        JTextArea display2=new JTextArea(12,12);
        display2.setEditable(true); 
        JScrollPane scroll2=new JScrollPane(display2);
        scroll2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        middlePanel.add(scroll2);
        window.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);    
        window.resize(700,500);

        /*
        JPanel pSouth = new JPanel();
        pSouth.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pSouth.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width/3, 50));*/
        //display2 = new JTextField(" ");
        //display2.setEditable(false);
        //display2.setFont(fontText);
        display2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()                
                {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
            {  /*
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) 
                {
                    textArea.append(getText() + ":" + display2.getText() + "\n");

                    //scrollToBottom();
                    //posaljiPoruku(display2.getText());
                    display2.setText(" \n"); 
                     }*/
            } 
                });
                id = new JTextField();
        id.setEditable( false );

        getContentPane().add( id, BorderLayout.NORTH );
    }

    public void createGUI()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
        {
            gameBtn[i] = new JButton(ButtonIcon);
            gameBtn[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
        HitScore = new JLabel("Acertou: " + Hit);
        MissScore = new JLabel("Falhou: " + Miss);
    TempoScore = new JLabel("Tempo: " + tempo);
    PontosScore = new JLabel("Pontos: " + Pontos);  
        exitBtn = new JButton("Sair");
        exitBtn.addActionListener(this);
        baralharBtn = new JButton("Baralhar");
        baralharBtn.addActionListener(this);
        solveBtn = new JButton("Resolver");
        solveBtn.addActionListener(this);
    restartBtn = new JButton("Recomecar");
        restartBtn.addActionListener(this);
    maximoBtn = new JButton("Pontuacoes");
        maximoBtn.addActionListener(this);
    definicoesBtn = new JButton("Definicoes");
        definicoesBtn.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void createJPanels()
    {
        gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
        {
            gamePnl.add(gameBtn[i]);
        }
        buttonPnl.add(baralharBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(exitBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(solveBtn);
    buttonPnl.add(restartBtn);
    buttonPnl.add(maximoBtn);
    buttonPnl.add(definicoesBtn);
        buttonPnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        scorePnl.add(HitScore);
        scorePnl.add(MissScore);
    scorePnl.add(TempoScore);
    scorePnl.add(PontosScore);
        scorePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        window.add(scorePnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(gamePnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.add(buttonPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);   
    }

    public void run()
    {
        // Primeiro a jogar jogador 1, segundo 2
        try 
        {          
            player=input.readChar();
            textArea.setText("You are player \""+ player + "\"");
            myTurn=(player == '1' ? true : false);
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();         
        }

        // Receive messages sent to client
        while ( true ) 
        {
            try 
            {
                String s = input.readUTF();
                processMessage( s );
            }
            catch ( IOException e ) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();         
            }
        }
    }

    public void processMessage( String s )
    {
        if ( s.equals( "Valid move." ) )  //s -> square
        {
            textArea.append( "Valid move, please wait.\n" );
             //currentSquare.setMark( myMark );
             //currentSquare.repaint();
        }
        else if ( s.equals( "Invalid move, try again" ) ) 
        {
            textArea.append( s + "\n" );
            myTurn = true;
        }
        else if ( s.equals( "Opponent moved" ) ) 
        {
            try 
            {
                int loc = input.readInt();
                 /*
                board[ loc / 3 ][ loc % 3 ].setMark(
                      ( myMark == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X' ) );
                board[ loc / 3 ][ loc % 3 ].repaint();
                      */
                textArea.append("Opponent moved. Your turn.\n" );
                myTurn = true;
            }
            catch ( IOException e ) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();         
            }
        }
        else
        textArea.append( s + "\n" );
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getText().length() );
   }

   public void sendClickedSquare( int loc )
   {
   if ( myTurn )
        try 
        {
            output.writeInt( loc );
            myTurn = false;
        }
         catch ( IOException ie ) 
        {
            ie.printStackTrace();         
        }
   }
   /*
   public void setCurrentSquare( Square s )
   {
      //currentSquare = s;
   }
} */

    // Maintains one square on the board
    class Square extends JPanel 
    {
        private char mark;
        private int location;

        public Square( char m, int loc)
        {
            mark = m;
            location = loc;
            setSize ( 30, 30 );

            setVisible(true);
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
        { 
            return ( new Dimension( 30, 30 ) );
        }

        public Dimension getMinimumSize() 
        {
            return ( getPreferredSize() );
        }

        public void setMark( char c ) { mark = c; }

        public int getSquareLocation() { return location; }

        public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
        {
            super.paintComponent( g );
            g.drawRect( 0, 0, 29, 29 );
            g.drawString( String.valueOf( mark ), 11, 20 );   
        }
    }

    public void setArrayListText() // gera numeros aleatorios
    { 
    List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    Collections.shuffle(lista);
    gameList.addAll(lista);
    }

    public boolean sameValues()
    {
        if (btnValue[0] == btnValue[1])
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (exitBtn == e.getSource())
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (baralharBtn == e.getSource())
        {
            List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
            Collections.shuffle(lista);
            gameList.addAll(lista);
        }

        if (solveBtn == e.getSource())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
            {   // enable false, ao clicar, não modifica o aspecto(cor) da quadricula,
        gameBtn[i].setEnabled(false); // enabled false-> cor cinzenta(padrão de fundo), true azul                
        gameBtn[i].setVisible(true); // visible true-> fica nºs visiveis
                gameBtn[i].setText("" + gameList.get(i));       
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
        {           
            if (gameBtn[i] == e.getSource())
            {
                gameBtn[i].setText("" + gameList.get(i));
                gameBtn[i].setEnabled(false);
                counter++;

        if(Hit==7)
        {
                    if (counter == 2)
                    {
            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(false);
            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(false);
            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setVisible(false);
            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setVisible(false);
            Hit = Hit +1;
            Pontos = Pontos + 25;
                    }                   
        }

        if(Hit==8)
        {  
                    int PontuacaoMax=0;
                    PontuacaoMax=Pontos;
                    window = new JFrame(" FIM DO JOGO ");           
                    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("\n PARABENS FINALIZOU O JOGO ! TOTAL DE PONTOS: "+PontuacaoMax);    
                    int[] anArray;
                    int w=0;
                    int h=1;
                    anArray = new int[20];
                    anArray[w] = PontuacaoMax;  
                    System.out.printf("Jogo %d,",h);
                    System.out.println(" Pontuacao final : "+PontuacaoMax);
                    w++;h++;
                    window.add("Center", label3);               
                    window.show();                      
                    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bruno.azevedo8\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Jogo_Memoria\\resources\\fogo.jpg");
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(img);
                    window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    window.pack();  
                    window.setVisible(true); 
                    gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(false);
                    gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(false);
                    gameBtn[btnID[0]].setVisible(true);
                    gameBtn[btnID[1]].setVisible(true);
                    cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
                    //AudioClip audio = Applet.newAudioClip(cl.getResource("C:\\Users\\bruno.azevedo8\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Memoria\\Jogo_Memoria\\resources\\bottle-open.wav"));
                    //audio.play();                 
                }

                if (counter == 3)
                {               
                    if (sameValues())
                    {
                        gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(false);
                        gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(false);
                        gameBtn[btnID[0]].setVisible(true);
                        gameBtn[btnID[1]].setVisible(true);
                        Hit = Hit +1;
                        Pontos = Pontos + 25;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(true);
                        gameBtn[btnID[0]].setText("");
                        gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(true);
                        gameBtn[btnID[1]].setText("");
                        Miss = Miss +1;
                        Pontos = Pontos - 5;                       
                    }
                    counter = 1; 
                }
                /*if (Pontos <= 0)
                {
                        Pontos=0;
                } */
                if (counter == 1) // na grelha identifica o 1º clique do rato
                {
                    btnID[0] = i;
                    btnValue[0] = gameList.get(i);
                }
                if (counter == 2) // na grelha identifica o 2º clique do rato(diferente do 1º)
                {
                    btnID[1] = i;
                    btnValue[1] = gameList.get(i);
                }
            }
        }

    if (restartBtn == e.getSource()) // apaga a grelha
        { 
            Hit=0;
            Miss=0;
            tempo=-1;
            Pontos=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
            {
                gameBtn[i].setText("");
                gameBtn[i].setEnabled(true);
                gameBtn[i].setVisible(true);    
            }
        }  

    if (maximoBtn == e.getSource()) //mostra melhor pontucao
        {
            window = new JFrame(" Jogo da Memoria - Melhores Pontuacoes:"); 
            int Max=0,PontuacaoMax=0;           

            //private static int maxValue(char[] chars) 
            //{
                //int  = chars[0]; 
                /*
                int[] anArray;
                anArray = new int[20];
                for (int w = 0; w < anArray.length; w++) 
                {
                    if (anArray[w]>= Max) 
                    {
                        Max = anArray[w];
                        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: "+Max);
                        window.add("Center", label2);
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(PontuacaoMax);
                JLabel label5 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao: " +PontuacaoMax );
                window.add("Center", label5); */
                //return Pontos;
            //}
            /*
            anArray[w]=0;
            int w;
            for(w=0;w<20;w++)
            {
                if (anArray[w]>=PontuacaoMax)
                {
                    PontuacaoMax=anArray[w];
                    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: "+PontuacaoMax);
                    window.add("Center", label2);
                }
            } 
            */ 
            if (Pontos >= PontuacaoMax)
            {
                PontuacaoMax = Pontos;
                JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: "+PontuacaoMax); 
                //Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<>();
                //v.add(PontuacaoMax);System.out.println(PontuacaoMax);
                window.add("Center", label2);
            }
            if (Pontos < PontuacaoMax)
            {
                PontuacaoMax = Pontos;
                JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: 0");         
                window.add("Center", label2);
            }    

            window.show();                      
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bruno.azevedo8\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Jogo_Memoria\\resources\\trofeu.jpg");         
            JLabel label = new JLabel(img); 
            window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            window.pack();  
            window.setVisible(true); 
        }

    if (definicoesBtn == e.getSource()) //mostra as definicoes
        {   

            definicoesBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {    
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento)
                {    
                    window = new JFrame(" Jogo da Memoria - Definicoes:");              
                    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Escolha Nivel Dificuldade:");           
                    window.add("West", label3);                                     
                    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bruno.azevedo8\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Jogo_Memoria\\resources\\definicoes.jpg");
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(img); 
                    window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
                    JRadioButton aRadioButton = new JRadioButton(" Facil ");
                    JRadioButton bRadioButton = new JRadioButton(" Medio ");
                    JRadioButton cRadioButton = new JRadioButton(" Dificil ");

                    ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() 
                    {
                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changEvent) 
                        {
                            AbstractButton aButton = (AbstractButton)changEvent.getSource();
                            ButtonModel aModel = aButton.getModel();
                            boolean armed = aModel.isArmed();
                            boolean pressed = aModel.isPressed();
                            boolean selected = aModel.isSelected();

                            aRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                            {
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                {                           
                                    gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
                                    //System.out.println("4x4");
                                }
                            });
                            bRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                            {
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                {                                       
                                    JButton[] gameBtn = new JButton[18];

                                     for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                                    {
                                        gameBtn[i] = new JButton(ButtonIcon);
                                        gameBtn[i].addActionListener(this);
                                    } 

                                    gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6)); /*
                                    for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                                    {
                                            gamePnl.add(gameBtn[i]);
                                    }           */                                                  
                                }
                            });
                            cRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                            {
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                {                                                                                   
                                    gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));                                                
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    };
                    panel.add(aRadioButton);
                    group.add(aRadioButton);
                    panel.add(bRadioButton);
                    group.add(bRadioButton);
                    panel.add(cRadioButton);
                    group.add(cRadioButton);
                    aRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                    bRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                    cRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                    window.add(panel);                      
                    window.pack();  
                    window.setVisible(true); 
                }    
            });             
        }
        updateHitMiss();
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {      
        new MemoryGame7();         
        try 
        {
            // criação do socket TCP de ligação ao servidor, o 1º argumento
            // é o nome da máquina, o 2º é o número do porto
            Socket sd = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(argv[0]), (new Integer(argv[1])).intValue());
            // obtenção dos canais de leitura e escrita do socket
            InputStream in = sd.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = sd.getOutputStream();
            // criação do buffer para envio e recepção de informação
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            for (;;) 
            {
                // pede a mensagem ao utilizador
                System.out.print("Introduza a mensagem: ");
                System.out.flush();
                int length = System.in.read(buffer);
                // envia ao servidor o buffer através do outputstream
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                out.flush();
                // se premiu return, fecho da ligação
                if (length == 1) break;
                // leitura da mensagem ecoada pelo servidor
                length = in.read(buffer);
                System.out.println(new String(buffer,0,0,length));
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
                // Surgiu algum problema com a ligação ao socket
                System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("ligação fechada");

    }
}
```

Servidor:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class ServidorMult2 
{
    protected final int DIM = 10;
    protected ServeCliente clientes[];
    protected ServerSocket SocketEscuta;
    public ServidorMult2 (int listenPort) throws IOException 
    {
        clientes = new ServeCliente[DIM];
        SocketEscuta = new ServerSocket(listenPort, DIM);
    }
    public void waitForClients()
    {
        int n = 0;
        try 
        { 
            while ( n < clientes.length )
            { 
                clientes[n] = new ServeCliente( this, SocketEscuta.accept(), n);
                clientes[n].start();
                n++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try 
        { 
            ServidorMult2 servidor = new ServidorMult2(5013);
            servidor.waitForClients(); 
        } 
                catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Erro:"); 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
}
class ServeCliente extends Thread 
{
    protected ServidorMult2 servidor; 
    protected Socket sockCliente; 
    protected int n; 
    protected InputStream input; 
    protected OutputStream output; 
    public ServeCliente(ServidorMult2 servidor, Socket sockCliente, int n) throws IOException 
    {
        this.servidor = servidor;
        this.sockCliente = sockCliente; 
        this.n = n;
        input = sockCliente.getInputStream();
        output = sockCliente.getOutputStream();
    }
    public void run () 
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try 
        {
            for (;;) 
            {
                int length =input.read(buffer);
                if ( length == 1 ) break;
                System.out.println("Cliente "+n+": "+new String(buffer,0,0,length));
                output.write(buffer,0,length);
            }
        }
                catch(IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: É o jogo da velha ou aquele jogo de peças iguais? Você quer fazer ele em `rede` né? Começa estudando os `Sockets` de java, é bem facinho de implementar algo servidor/cliente. Quanto a tua dúvida, ela está muito ampla, parece que você quer que façamos teu dever, tenta elaborar melhor.

Comment: É o jogo da Memória (peças iguais). Já estudei sockets, já implementei cliente e servidor, mas ainda está imcompleto.

Comment: Tenho um dúvida especifica como mostro para o